# MongoDB (mongoose) - Find documents and sort with specific key value

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

### Employees

```
[
    { name: 'John', company: 'Apple' },
    { name: 'Mike', company: 'Microsoft' },
    { name: 'Tim', company: 'Microsoft' },
    { name: 'Steve', company: 'Amazon' },
    { name: 'Bob', company: 'Facebook' },
    { name: 'Kevin', company: 'Facebook' },
    { name: 'Jude', company: 'Google' },
    { name: 'Kim', company: 'Google' },

    ... (many docs)
]
```

I want order above documents by company name.

Want to sort by `Apple` => `Google` => And the others.

Expected:

```
[
{ name: 'John', company: 'Apple' },
{ name: 'Jude', company: 'Google' },
{ name: 'Kim', company: 'Google' }, 

... (and the others)
]
```

**How could I do this with mongoose?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an Aggregation query using `$filter` in combination with `$concatArrays`.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$project": {
      "companies": {
        "$concatArrays": [
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$employees",
              "as": "appleElem",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$appleElem.company",
                  "Apple"  // <-- Company name you want in first order
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$employees",
              "as": "appleElem",
              "cond": {
                "$eq": [
                  "$$appleElem.company",
                  "Google"  // <-- Company name you want in second order
                ]
              }
            }
          },
          {
            "$filter": {
              "input": "$employees",
              "as": "appleElem",
              "cond": {
                "$not": {
                  "$in": [
                    "$$appleElem.company",
                    [  // <-- Company names that should be ignored from sorting
                      "Apple",
                      "Google"
                    ]
                  ]
                }
              }
            }
          },
          
        ],
        
      },
      
    }
  }
])
```

[Mongo Playground Test and Result](https://mongoplayground.net/p/KrCuqPHYTOM)

Comment: Hi.. Thanks for your answer. But the playground omit a syntax error. And How do I set "Apple => Google" Part? I couldn't find

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience, mistook your question statement at first. Fixed the answer.

Comment: Wow...you are a genius!